# Xcode ignores Texture Atlas inside a subfolder

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I have a case where I need to keep the folders hierarchy in my iOS app bundle, which contains some texture atlases. However, unlike the case with group referencing, Xcode seems to ignore any texture atlas under directory that's referenced as a folder not a group. Any workaround for this?

Comment: I'm having this problem too. In fact, for me, if naming a folder rather than a group, the texture atlases don't seem to generate, let alone textures in subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried renaming and adding the ".atlas" at the end of the folder's name, dragging it to your project again and keeping the following option ticked?  copy items into des... Create groups for any ... add to targets (your project selected)

Comment: When I add a folder with the option of folder referencing to it, Xcode won't let me add anything to it from its Project Navigator. The only way I can add/remove files/folders is by using Finder, which is equal of adding them with their parent folders. Also, all texture atlases already have the ".atlas" extension where they're.

Answer (score 0):

In `Xcode` it's not enough move your folder to the `Assets.xcassets`. You must go inside `Assets` and select *AR and SceneKit > Sprite Atlas* , rename the folder and move all your sprites inside it.

**P.S.** remember to remove your app from the simulator/device before to launch the corrected `Assets`.